# Unable to display selected dropdown value after submit

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am unable to display the selected dropdown value after clicking on submit.

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/page1/send}" th:object="${val}" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" name="action" id="action" th:value="${value}">
           <option th:selected="'ABC' == ${value}">ABC</option>
           <option th:selected="'XYZ' == ${value}">XYZ</option>                 
    </select>
 </form>
```

In the controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping("/page1/send")
public String send(Values val, Model model) { 
String value = val.getValue();                             
    model.addAttribute("value",value);
    return "page1";
}
```

When I select XYZ and submit, it again reverts back to ABC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I select XYZ and submit

I dont see submit button in your form. However i understood what you require. Let say page1.html is first loaded by some controller method as below

```
@GetMapping(path = "/")
    public ModelAndView home()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("value", "XYZ");
        mav.setViewName("page1");
        return mav;
    }
```

This serves the below html page form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/page1/send}"  method="post">
    <select class="form-control" name="action" id="action">
        <option th:selected="'ABC' == ${value}" value="ABC">ABC</option>
        <option th:selected="'XYZ' == ${value}" value="XYZ">XYZ</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now i can read value of submitted dropdown and send it back to page from controller method as

```
@RequestMapping("/page1/send")
    public String testSubmit(@RequestParam("action") String action, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("value",action);
        return "page1";
    }
```

Let me know if that helps.